# Statistical creativity needed for a study in criminal behaviour...HELP

Tags: probability, prediction

I have a question for a study involving psychology, linguistics, and criminology.  All me to walk you through the labyrinth...

Let's say we have a criminal whose original name is John Howard Smith (or to use letters, A B C).
That criminal then selects the alias Howard Smith (B C).
What statistical test can I use to determine the probability that another offender whose real name matches the pattern of (A B C) will select the same alias pattern (B C)?

And extending the question to a group of offenders....

Let's now say I have data set with four offenders with the following real names and name patterns: 
OFFENDERS                         ORIGINAL PATTERNS
1.) John Howard Smith        A B C
2.) Gregory Thomas             A C
3.) Carlos Gomez-Rodriguez  A B-C
4.)  A.G. Keating                     A. B. C

And then I look at the aliases that the above set of offenders used to form my base observations

1.) A B C                     becomes        B C    (i.e. Howard Smith)
2.) AC                        becomes        C A     (i.e. Thomas Gregory)
3.) A B-C                     becomes        A C     (i.e. Carlos Rodriguez)
4.) A. B. C                   becomes        A.  C    (i.e. A. Keating)

Now I expand my data-set to include hundreds of offenders with their accompanying aliases; and I now determine the frequencies with which offenders whose original names fall within a particular pattern select aliases with particular patterns.  For example, amongst the offenders whose real name has the pattern A B C, I find that

50% select an alias with the pattern B C (i.e. Howard Smith) TRANSFORMATION TYPE 1
10% select an alias with the pattern A C  (i.e. John Smith) TRANFORMATION TYPE 2
30% select an alias with the pattern B A C  (i.e. Howard John Smith) TRANSFORMATION TYPE 3
10% select an alias with the pattern B. C   (i.e. H. Smith) TRANSFORMATION TYPE 4

I now do precisely the same for all of the different original name patterns I find in my original data-set.

Once I have this set of observations, what analysis would I need to use to determine the probability that a  new offender, who was not a part of my originally observed set, will take on an alias that follows Transformation Type 1 as opposed to Transformation Type 2, etc.???

Cheers,
Nick